# Proof: If $r \in R$ is irreducible then $ur$ is irreducible where $u$ is a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

If $r \in R$ is irreducible then $r=ab, a,b \in R$ implies $a$ or $b$ is a unit.

How does one proof $ur$ is irreducible if $u$ is a unit.

I must proof: $ur = mn, m, n\in R$ then $m$ or $n$ is a unit.

Suppose $n$ is a unit, then we are done. However, if $n$ is not a unit, then I can write $r = u^{-1}mn$. This implies $(u^{-1}m) $ is a unit. Hence there exists $(u^{-1}m)^{-1} $ such that
$(u^{-1}m)(u^{-1}m)^{-1}$ = 1 = $(u^{-1}m)^{-1}u^{-1})m)$ and hence $m$ has a left inverse. How do I proof that it has a right inverse equal to $(u^{-1}m)^{-1}u^{-1})\in R$ ?

May I just expand $(u^{-1}m)^{-1} = m^{-1}u$ to conclude $m$ has an inverse ? In the expansion I assume $m^{-1}$ exists ?

/Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from $ur = mn$. Then $r = (u^{-1} m) n$. Now either $n$ is a unit, or $u^{-1} m$ is, and thus also $m = u (u^{-1} m)$, as a product of two units.

Comment: Why $u^{-1} m$ is unit??

Comment: It's either/or, as $r$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas